# Asp.Net core app previously running identity converting to Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication

I am trying to convert a .net core 2.2 app from running Identity with User and Roles, using Email/Password to login, to essentially the same app with the users and roles still supported via Identity, but the login goes away and the username is extracted from ADS and used as a lookup into the existing User table.
One of the issue is that not ALL ADS user that hit the app - will have access, so these users essentially will NOT be able to signin to identity and therefore will get thrown out of the app

I was thinking I need to create a custom Identity provider which finds the user and works similar to the normal Identity model but with the signIn component reqritten to find the User object the new way? Then once a user is 'signed in', they would have all the original Roles added to the claims etc.

Open to options on way forward to get this to work
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

configure IISServerOptions in Startup.cs

```
 services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(opt=>{
            opt.AutomaticAuthentication=true;
            opt.AuthenticationDisplayName="auth";
        });
```

then  implement you own IClaimsTransformation to validate the user with AD